how does one prove infringement of a back end server method that cannot be seen by the client?
Let's suppose that invention is a server that returns a list of results to the client user in a novel and non-obvious way.
However, the method and algorithm that enables the server to return the list of results in under 1 second as opposed to 1 hour cannot be seen or deduced by the client.
This implementation detail of the server that enables efficiency is not described in my patent specifications.
Questions:

If someone were to patent the efficient back end server method and algorithm, how can they prove that I'm infringing upon them?
Would they even have any grounds to sue me, given that they can't possibly know what method or algorithm I am using to generate the list?


I am not a lawyer. I do know there is such a thing as “discovery” during law suits.

but isn't that based upon some sort of reasonable evidence or assumption? Can you really invoke a a lawsuit just based sole on a blind guess?

Any business that operates a web service should be prepared that it may have to disclose some aspects of its operations should it be hit by a patent lawsuit. There are some avenues for attempting to protect trade secrets from discovery, but it's generally an uphill battle: https://www.jstor.org/stable/25762526

In the US, at least, anyone can sue for pretty much any reason.
